# Python: Removing elements near the front of a list efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, list, deque

Is there a way to remove elements from the start of a long list of numbers? Right now I am doing del arr[i:i+x] but it is slow since it has to move everything past that point to the left, which is time-consuming for large lists.

I looked into deques but not sure if those apply here. Could use some direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)s do apply here, you should use them, it will be very fast if they are very near the front but slower if the start index is located towards the middle.

> Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> def delete_slice(d, start, stop):
        d.rotate(-start)
        for i in range(stop-start): # use xrange on Python 2
            d.popleft()
        d.rotate(start)


>>> d = deque(range(15))
>>> delete_slice(d, 5, 10)
>>> d
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

**Note:** Rotating past the middle, as previously stated, will be slow, if you want to support fast deletions from the right side you can extend the code like so:

```
def delete_slice(d, start, stop):
    stop = min(stop, len(d)) # don't go past the end
    start = min(start, stop) # don't go past stop
    if start < len(d) // 2:
        d.rotate(-start)
        for i in range(stop-start): # use xrange on Python 2
            d.popleft()
        d.rotate(start)
    else:
        n = len(d) - stop
        d.rotate(n)
        for i in range(stop - start):
            d.pop()
        d.rotate(-n)
```

Of course there is some other error checking you will need to do but I'll leave that  out of here for simplicity's sake. Unfortunately these methods are not already provided by `deque` itself, so you have to implement them like this.

> To implement deque slicing, use a similar approach applying `rotate()` to bring a target element to the left side of the `deque`. Remove old entries with `popleft()`, add new entries with `extend()`, and then reverse the rotation. With minor variations on that approach, it is easy to implement Forth style stack manipulations such as dup, drop, swap, over, pick, rot, and roll.

Comment: How would I correctly remove the elements? Or declaring a deque of length x?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) applies here. Have prepared an example which shows how to use it:

```
import collections

"create deque from list"
d=collections.deque([1,2,3,4,5,6])
"remove first element"
d.popleft()

print d
```

Output:

```
deque([2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: What if the deque were of length 10000 and you wanted to remove the 5th element from the left?

Comment: @hek2mgl the question is about deleting slices though

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing several deletions in a row, it might be more efficient to create a new list using a generator with a filter:

```
arr = [e for e in arr if not rejected(e)]
```

If you need to work with indexes, you can use enumerate:

```
arr = [e for i, e in enumerate(arr) if not rejected(i)]
```

Both operations are O(n) (O(2*n) in space), while performing several deletions in a row is O(n*m) (but O(n) in space).

`deque` has this characteristic, which may not be what you want:

> Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you probably want a tree or skiplist.

I did a study of Python tree implementations a while back:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/python-tree-and-heap-comparison/

You might be better off asking about this in the algorithms section of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are not optimized for appending or popping at the front. Deques are, though.

Note also that the `deque.remove(item)` in [the CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c) will search from the front. If you need to move/remove queue items frequently, you may benefit from considering whether most items to be removed will be near the end and use the queue flipped if that is the case, i.e. `appendleft` and `pop` instead of `append` and `popleft`.